# Wifi disabled in Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 5448

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron 5448 (previously I had Windows 10 on this computer). The wifi (Intel Wireless 7265) does not work with the live disk neither does after installation. I also tried two USB-Wifi Adaptors, one from Cisco (Linksys WUSB100 Range Plus) and one from TP-LINK (Realtek RTL8188EUS). The adaptors do not work either, but both work plug and play on my Manjaro XFCE installation at home (Kernel 14.04).

In the top right drop down menu of the Ubuntu Desktop I get PCI Wi-Fi OFF and/or USB Wi-Fi OFF, but clicking on the option *Turn on* does not have any effect. The *Wi-FI settings* shows *No Wi-Fi Adaptor Found*, although on the top of the window it is written *Wireless  7265 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265)*. Both show as disabled (see below).

I already a attempted several instruction from several forums without success. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

The output of the wireless script is available [here (with the TP-Link adaptor also plugged in)](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Kzv7JszGhY/).

Comment: According to this: https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-14-5448-laptop_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf the wireless is activated with Fn+PrtScr. Is there any improvement if you press the key combination?

Comment: No. This key combination only activates/deactivates airplane mode.

Comment: Press it and run: `rfkill list all` Press again and again run: `rfkill list all` Is there any change at all in the output?

Comment: @chili555 Yes.
'0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no'

'0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no'

Comment: Is the module *dell_rbtn* loaded? `lsmod | grep dell`

Comment: @chili555 The solution provided by Seth Bergman worked. Now dell_rbtn is not loaded. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the output of your wireless script linked in your question, I believe you need to blacklist the `dell-rbtn` module:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
blacklist dell_rbtn
```

Also, make sure [secure boot is disabled](https://www.appgeeker.com/recovery/disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-10.html) in BIOS.

Comment: In the list of loaded modules, I don't see *dell_rbtn* listed at all.

Comment: @SethBergman That worked, thanks!  The behaviour seems a bit erratic, because deactivation of wi-fi immediately enables airplane mode. But it works!

Comment: @chili555 that is strange, but it worked. I note that secure boot was already disabled in BIOS.

Comment: @Rodrigo Castelan Carlson I'm happy to help. As far as airplane mode goes, you might check out the network manager and make sure it's properly configured. @chill555 maybe the world module is not the correct way to reference it. It's under the `rfkill` section of the script. This is just a way to keep the hard lock disabled after rebooting.